# цикл for с двумя переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу внутри одного цикла, с двумя переменными, с помощью принтов выводить ссылки + цену.
Сейчас всё валится с ошибкой, чё то не могу понять в какую сторону смотреть.
Если разделять на два цикла, то по отдельности всё нормально работает.
Подскажите куда смотреть.

```
request = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

all_links = bs.find_all("a", class_="link-link-MbQDP link-design-default-_nSbv title-root-j7cja iva-item-title-_qCwt title-listRedesign-XHq38 title-root_maxHeight-SXHes")
all_links1 = bs.find_all("meta", itemprop="price")

# for link1 in all_links1:     #
#     print(link1['content'])  #
#                              # отдельно всё работает, но создаётся соответственно два списка
# for link in all_links:       #
#     print(link['href'])      #

for link in all_links, all_links1:
    print(link["href"] + link["content"])
```

`print(link["href"] + link["content"])`

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: `for link, link1 in zip(all_links, all_links1)`

Comment: @EzikBro
Именно то что надо, zip пробовал сам но с одним link. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я могу рассказать на примере Авито, тоже недавно парсил. В общем, тебе нужно сначала найти весь блок объявлений, а потом раскладывать их на части. Как сделал я:
`data = bs.find("div", class_="items-items-kAJAg").find_all("div", class_="iva-item-root-Nj_hb")` Поясню: find() - вернул мне весь(то есть ОДИН) блок, со всеми объявлениями, затем find_all() - вернул мне ВСЕ объявления, которые есть в блоке, который мы искали при помощи find(). Получается как-то сложно, либо я не умею объяснять. На скрине ОДИН видно, что я выбрал блок со ВСЕМИ объявлениями, затем нужно записать его класс в find(), а потом, как я сделал на скрине ДВА, выбрать одно объявление и записать его класс в find_all(). Затем циклов for перебирать всю что входит в переменную data

```
    for value1 in data:
        try:
            title = value1.find("h3", itemprop="name").text.strip()
        except:
            title = ""
        try:
            price = value1.find("span", class_="price-text-E1Y7h").text.strip().replace("\xa0", "")
            #print(price)
        except:
            price = ""
        try:
            link = "https://www.avito.ru/" + value1.find("a", class_="iva-item-title-_qCwt")["href"]
        except:
            link = ""
```

Вот, переменные по типу title, price и link естественно можно менять на свои.

P.s: Это был мой первый ответ на форуме, не суди строго, как смог - так объяснил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня всё работало, только не мог прогнать две переменные в одном цикле, что бы сразу и заголовок объявления отображался + его цена. Предыдущий комментарий мне в этом сполна помог, всё получилось. Но всё равно спасибо за уделённое время))